# Specifying the VirtualHost to serve up when there is no DNS Name sent in the HTTP Headers?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

In Apache 2 how does one specify the (VirtualHost?) that is served up when no DNS Name is set in the HTTP Headers of a request?

Comment: Assuming I have other VirtualHosts setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [apache2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) says that when a `VirtualHost`...

> is first in the configuration file, it has the highest priority and can be seen as the default or primary server.

So, the first one will answer requests that do not explicitly match another `VirtualHost` through their `ServerName` directive or separate ip.